# 301 Redirect from URL with Hashtag to URL without

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've found many posts for how to 301 to a URL with a hashtag but I'm needing to go the opposite direction.  I have a URL such as this:

```
http://example.com/page1.html#someproduct2
```

and I need to redirect it to:

```
http://example.com/products/new-product-2
```

I know I can't use PHP to grab the # so I'm not sure what options I have for this type of redirect.

Comment: Javascript only. Hashtags are client side only.

Comment: The server doesn't see `#someproduct2`, only the `http://example.com/page1.html` part.